# Unable to delete data from json object in titanium

Tags: javascript, android, json, titanium-mobile

I am developing Android application using Titanium. I want to delete and push some new data in to json object.I used following code:

```
var jsonfeed = this.responseText;
var jsontext = JSON.parse(jsonfeed);
```

My json object give below:

```
{"feeds":
[
   {"username":"abc","user":"abc","feed":{"description":"dss","id":660,"user_id":1}},
   {"username":"bcd","user":"bcd","feed":{"description":"dddd","id":659,"user_id":1}}
]
}
```

I want to delete jsontext.feeds[0]. I tried Splice like **jsontext.feeds.splice(0,1)** it returns correct value but it actually not deleting any value from jsontext.Is there any way to delete data from json object or any suggestion about my code.Thank you.

Comment: See the question at http://stackoverflow.com/q/208105

You use the delete keyword.

Answer (score 0):

what about try using shift()

```
alert(jsontext.feeds[0].username) // abc

  // shift the beginning of the array
  jsontext.feeds.shift();

alert(jsontext.feeds[0].username) //bcd  ?
```

Comment: Thank you david for reply.I tried it but it's not working.Is there any problem in accessing json object.Because splice also not working

Comment: i did not use `var jsontext = JSON.parse(jsonfeed);` but placed your json object inplace of `JSON.parse(jsonfeed)` pluse i only tested it windows, FF, chrome ,and IE

Comment: @nilkash is the json data being created localy or are you receiving it for a external server you don't have control over? im just asking if so try without json.parse

Comment: I am receiving json object from external server not created localy

Comment: My server side code returning me json object which looks similar given in the question.